# How to merge home page and Navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have to design an application like online shopping apps. I made a home page as well as navigation drawer but both are  design separately now i need to marge the both activities. please suggest how to merge it.

Home

[image: this is home page and i want to add navigation drawer on left upper corner]

Nav

[image: this is a navigation drawer that i need to add on home page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these screens should have their own XML, right?

So therefore, both can be made into Fragments. That's Step 1.

Then, you make a new Activity layout using DrawerLayout. You may use the template that Android Studio provides, but that'll include lots of Java code that you may not need, but the XML generated there will give you an idea.

The general layout will roughly  be

```
DrawerLayout 

    CoordinatorLayout 
        AppBarLayout 
            Toolbar 
        /AppBarLayout

        FrameLayout  :id = container 

    /CoordinatorLayout

    fragment :class = package.name.YourDrawerFragment

/DrawerLayout
```

And you use optionally replace the inner FrameLayout with an XML `<include>` tag if you aren't wanting to use Fragments there.

It looks like you already have the Drawer established, so you simply need to load content "behind it"